# Flask Select field - Not a valid choice

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have the following code in form.py

```
OPTIONS = ['Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3']
class Test_Form(Form):
    test = SelectField('Dropdown', coerce= str, 
                                      choices=[(f, f) for f in OPTIONS])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

And the following code in my template

```
    <div class = "control-group">
        <label class="control-label">
            {{ form.test.label }} </label>
        {% if form.test.errors %}
            {% for error in form.test.errors  %}
                <p class="error-message"> {{ error }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}     
        <div class="controls">
            <select name=form.test.label width="80px">
                {% for i,j in form.test.choices %}
                    <option value = {{ i }} > {{ j }} </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Following is my view function

```
def show_logs():
    my_form = Test_Form()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if logs_form.validate() == False:
            return render_template('test.html', form = my_form)
        else:
            return my_form.test.data
            #return render_template('test_success.html', output = output_list)
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('test.html', form = my_form)
```

I get a "Not a Valid Choice" every time I submit the form. I went through the previous questions on SO and tried `coerce = str` but I still get the same message. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and it works perfectly on my end. The only thing I changed however was your template code as yours was incomplete. It had no submit button and no `<form>` tag declaration.
This is the template code that I used:

```
<form action="" method='post'>

        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <ul class="request_form">
            {%if form.errors%}
                Please correct the following fields: 
                {%for each in form.errors%}
                    <br>{{each}} 
                {%endfor%}
            {%endif%}

            {%for each in form%}
            {%if each.name != "csrf_token" and each.name!="submit"%}
            <li>
                <label>{{each.name}}</label>
                {{each()}}
            </li>
            {%endif%}
            {%endfor%}
            <li/>{{form.submit}}
        </ul>
</form>
```

Also, in your view, you're checking for `logs_form.validate()` when it should be `my_form.validate()` 
I hope this solves your problem.